# Java Put in specific order to treemap

Tags: java, string, collections, treemap

I have a big list and put it into a treemap.

Then I want to put "ALL" at the very top of the list, but there is "AAA" something that comes before "ALL"

edit: And I want all other inputs to be sorted

```
List     ->    List
-----          -----
AAA            AAA
BBB            ALL
CCC            BBB
               CCC
```

I could use arrayList or something else but I was wondering 
if there is a way to control this situation.

Comment: So you want ALL to remain on top no matter what you add?

Comment: Do you want the rest (entries other than key='ALL') to be sorted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to build a custom comparator that always ranks the word "ALL" before everything else:

```
TreeMap<String, T> myMap = new TreeMap<String, T>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        /* See which of the inputs, if any, are ALL. */
        bool oneAll = lhs.equals("ALL");
        bool twoAll = rhs.equals("ALL");

        /* If both are ALL or neither are ALL, just do a normal comparison. */
        if (oneAll == twoAll) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
        /* Otherwise, exactly one of them is ALL.  Determine which one it is and
         * react accordingly.
         */
        else if (oneAll) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return +1;
        }
    }
});
```

This will sort everything in ascending order, but prioritize `"ALL"` above everything else.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `TreeMap`, basically. If you want to put things in a specific order, just use an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList` instead. `TreeMap` orders its entries in the order of its keys. You don't want that in this case.

EDIT: If you're *just* concerned with putting ALL at the top, then a custom comparator is fine. But if you really want to be able to specify the position of each entry in a way which isn't easily determined purely by the keys involved, then I stand by my suggestion that `TreeMap` is not the way forward.

Comment: I think that the OP wants to have everything sorted, but for `"ALL"` to always come at the top.  If that's the case, this solution might not be ideal.

Comment: totally disagree.  If we can't control the order of insertion, TreeMap is ideal. That's why there is a Comparator< T > interface.

Comment: @JudgeMental: It depends on whether the order is due to the key itself, or some external option. If it's *just* a case of "ALL" comes before everything, then that can be done with a `Comparator`. If you need data other than what's in the key, it's not really appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own  `compareTo()`  so that ALL always comes on top

Answer (score 1):

Using LinkedHashMap would allow you to keep the same order as element added to map. If you need a custom order you can use your own Comparator with TreeMap.